cursor.execute problem , is giving error when i try to insert data
i have 3 pages , and i have a page where calls the info of the first page and makes calculation and give me error with placeholders (i asked chatgpt)
when i try to insert a producy gives me this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bruno\FilamentManager\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1498, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bruno\FilamentManager\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1476, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bruno\FilamentManager\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bruno\FilamentManager\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bruno\FilamentManager\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bruno\FilamentManager\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bruno\FilamentManager\app.py", line 74, in products
    cursor.execute('''
  File "C:\Users\bruno\FilamentManager\venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 367, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement


My code
cursor.execute('''
            INSERT INTO products (name, photo, filament_id_1, amount_1, cost_1, filament_id_2, amount_2, cost_2, filament_id_3, amount_3, cost_3, filament_id_4, amount_4, cost_4, filament_id_5, amount_5, cost_5, filament_id_6, amount_6, cost_6, electricity, electricityc, extra, extra2, selling_price, total, profit, gp)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        ''', parameters)


what is parameters type ?

Count of %ss is 27 while count of column names is 28…
